# How to write an expression which generates all possible pairs regardless of order?

Tags: scala, combinatorics

I want to make an interface for entering something akin to a covariance matrix. For this, I need to create all empty "cells" in which the data will be entered. But of course, I don't want the user to enter the covariance of A and B when he has already entered the covariance of B and A.

Let's assume that I have the data points A through D as a `List("A", "B", "C", "D")`. I can then write the expression

```
val dataPoints = List("A", "B", "C", "D")
for(firstDataPoint <- dataPoints; secondDataPoint <- dataPoints) 
  yield (firstDataPoint, secondDataPoint)
```

This gives me all possible combinations, and I can create one "cell" per combination, but the trouble is that both ("A", "B") and ("B", "A") are present.

The only idea I can come up with is to create an empty mutable collection, loop over the result of the above code, check if the opposite pair is already in the mutable collection, and if not, write it into the mutable collection. But this solution seems like bad Scala style to me, and also inefficient (why create all values and immediately discard almost half?) I also want to learn to be better in functional programming, and while Scala has the tools for me to do that, it wouldn't have worked in a purely functional language.

Note that my actual data points don't have an inherent ordering, so I can't say that I throw out all combinations where `secondDataPoint<firstDataPoint`.

Is there a smarter way to do that?

Answer (score 1):

Since your elements are not ordered, you can do that by checking order of your elements in a list (since a list is ordered by index of an element). So, just check if the indexes are different:

```
val dataPoints = List("A", "B", "C", "D")
for(firstDataPoint <- dataPoints; secondDataPoint <- dataPoints) 
  if(dataPoints.indexOf(firstDataPoint) >=  dataPoints.indexOf(secondDataPoint)){
   yield (firstDataPoint, secondDataPoint)
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you! I dismissed the comparison idea quite early, because I'm using a nominal scale, before ever thinking where these values are stored (e.g. in an ordered List). Now that I see the solution, it's very obvious in hindsight.

Answer (score 1):

Just use the built-in `combinations` method:

```
List("A", "B", "C", "D").combinations(2)
```

This returns an `Iterator`. It should be enough for most purposes, but you can of course convert it to `List` to look at the results:

```
scala> List("A", "B", "C", "D").combinations(2).toList
res1: List[List[String]] = List(List(A, B), List(A, C), List(A, D), List(B, C), List(B, D), List(C, D))
```

As you see it also doesn't include pairs of the same element (e.g., `List("A", "A")`). It might be OK for your purposes (as in a correlation matrix all elements on the principal diagonal are trivially equal to 1). But you can add them if you want:

```
scala> val dataPoints = List("A", "B", "C", "D")
scala> (dataPoints.combinations(2) ++ 
        (dataPoints map (el => List(el, el)))).toList
res2: List[List[String]] = List(List(A, B), List(A, C), List(A, D), List(B, C), List(B, D), List(C, D), List(A, A), List(B, B), List(C, C), List(D, D))
```

Comment: You can just zipWithIndex the collection, then indexOf becomes O(1). See my answer

Comment: @Paul Yeah. Come to think to it my solution is also cubic, because indexing is linear for lists.

Answer (score 1):

Variant of @user987339's answer that removes the O(N) indexOf. @user987339, feel free to include this in your answer and I'll delete this one, it's only a minor tweak to yours.

```
val dataPoints = List("A", "B", "C", "D")
val indexedDataPoints = dataPoints zipWithIndex
for(firstDataPoint <- indexedDataPoints; secondDataPoint <- indexedDataPoints) 
  if(firstDataPoint._2) >= secondDataPoint._2)){
   yield (firstDataPoint._1, secondDataPoint._1)
  }
}
```